# Netbeans source tab disappears

Tags: netbeans

I have a problem with Netbeans that whenever I create a new project I couldn't find the source tab and I found history tab only. View->Editors show history option only as well. I try to reinstall the Netbeans but the problem remains..
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 36):

Click on menu [View] --> [Show Editor Toolbar]

Comment: Nope. In my case, that Editor Toolbar continues to be missing Source and History buttons. Despite the presence of .git in the project src path, and Git plugin in Netbeans

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem yesterday and I had to delete the Netbeans Cache and User Directory. Once I did it worked fine. You can find these under Help --> About. Once deleted reopen Netbeans and it should work.

Sources:
https://forums.netbeans.org/topic59936.html

User Directory is the folder 8.1 in the path: 
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans\8.1

and that worked for me too

Answer (score 3):

menu-bar>>**[View]>>[Show Editor Toolbar]**
[image]