# Netbeans Project not Showing

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-13

If I open or create a new project for java in Netbeans 8 it shows nothing only a blank tab, the code is missing. Then I try to use a different version, the Netbeans 13 with JDK 18 it still has the same problem. I don't know what goes wrong the installation is fine though. I try to create another project in html5 in Netbeans 13 and it works fine. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Immediately to the left of that "History" button in your screenshot there should be a "Source" button. That button is missing. Does [this answer for the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32362583/12567365) help? You have to delete the NetBeans cache directory (and apparently also the user directory), and then restart. You can see where these 2 directories are located by going to Help > About. I would just delete the cache directory to start with, and see if that is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I install another alternative for netbeans and i found eclipse so i will try to familiarize with it but i will try to do what you had suggested when i reinstall netbeans again.